# Shutdown console application after quartz schedule

Tags: c#, console-application, quartz.net

I was wondering how I could shutdown my Console Application after a Quartz schedule finishes.

```
var schedular = await GetScheduler();
await schedular.Start();

await scheduler.ScheduleJob(GetActivityReportDetailJob(), GetSimpleTrigger(nameof(ActivityReportDetailJob)));

Thread.Sleep(2000);
await scheduler.Shutdown();
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Well the first problem would be that I can't use ContinueWith() to call so I resorted to using Thread.Sleep(). I couldn't figure out how to make Quartz return anything else than just a Task. However, when getting to the Environment.Exit(0). I get:

Waiting for the host to be disposed. Ensure all 'IHost' instances are wrapped in 'using' blocks.

EDIT:

my main:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
                {
                    configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    configHost.AddJsonFile(Constants.Hostsettings, optional: true);
                    configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: Constants.Prefix);
                    configHost.AddCommandLine(args);
                })
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                {
                    configApp.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    configApp.AddJsonFile(Constants.Appsettings, optional: true);
                    configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
                    configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: Constants.Prefix);
                    configApp.AddCommandLine(args);
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddLogging();
                    services.AddHostedService<PollingService>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
                {
                    configLogging.AddConsole();
                })
                .UseConsoleLifetime()
                .Build();

            try
            {
                await host.RunAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

I am not sure where this using statement is suppose to be placed.

Answer (score 0):

try return statement from main function of main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {            
        return; //This will exit the console application's running thread
    }
}
```

or

System.Environment.Exit(-1);

Comment: Just added my main to the question.

Comment: do you require to use await for host.RunAsync(); ?

Comment: honestly unsure, this is my first project creating 'a service'.

Comment: you can remove and use code like                                                                       
          try
            {
                await host.RunAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }